# Hide children first and then reduce width of parent

Tags: jquery

I have the layout as follows:

```
<div id="outerwrap">
          <div id="innerwrap">      
             <div id="centerc">...</div>          

             <div id="rightc" style="font-weight:bold">
          </div>
          <div style="background-color:White;height:10px;top:284px;left:0px"></div>

          <div id="leftc">..</div>
        </div>
       <div id="footer"">...</div>

    #outerwrap
    {
       background-color: #EE44E7;
    }

    #innerwrap
    {
       background-color: #EE44E7;
       margin-right: 200px;
       top:0px;
       height:100%;
    }


    #leftc
    {
       position: absolute;
       top: 111px;
       left: 0px;
       width: 197px;
       background-color: #EE44E7;
       font-size: 10px;
    }

    #centerc
    {
       position: relative;
       margin-left: 199px;
       padding: 0px;
       background-color: white;
    }

    #rightc
    {
       position: absolute;
       top:111px;
       right: 0px;         
       width: 199px;
       color: blue;
       background-color: #EE44E7;
       font-size: 10px;
    }


#footer
    {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
visibility: hidden;
    }
```

The div leftc has children elements including images inside it.

What I want to do is that when the page loads, the children of leftc should be hidden and the leftc should have  width=20px. When the user hovers the mouse 'on' leftc, the leftc should become 197px wide with smooth animation and children should now be visible. When user hovers 'out' the mouse, the children should be hidden and leftc width should be 20px only with animation.

How can I do this in jQuery that works on all browsers including IE8. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#leftc").css("width", "20px").children().css("display", "none");

  $("#leftc").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({ width: "197px" }).children().css("display", "block/inline");
  }, function() {
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({ width: "20px" }).children().css("display", "none");
  });
  ...
});
```

**edit**: my bad, I mis-read your question, just select all children and hide them (:

**2nd edit:** see code above for hover-fix. You can use the `stop()` function to stop all animations on that element, so that you'll start off fresh every time.
If you want to do it with a click event, you can simply set a flag like so:

```
var leftActive = false;
$("#leftc").click(function() {
  if (leftActive) {
    $(this).animate({ width: "20px" }).children().css("display", "none");
    leftActive = false;
  } else {
    $(this).animate({ width: "197px" }).children().css("display", "block/inline");
    leftActive = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to hide all children elements, not only images

Comment: Thanks got it working now..There is one issue though..the hover in/out also occurs when my mouse goes to the extreme left of the leftc (touching the  corners of the browser)..this causes the behaviour to go out of control...any suggestions for this?

Comment: and apart from the above issue, i was thinking that can the mouse hover in/out can be replaced with click? So i click once, the panel shows, then click again and the panel hides? is that possible..thanks for all your help